# How do capture row selected in gridview and pass username value to text box in the next page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to select the gridview and redirect to the next page where username in gridview passed to the text box in the next page when the row is being clicked. How do i do that?

My code behind (on the first page):

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowSelected(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    var username = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
    Response.Redirect("ViewUploads.aspx?USERNAME=" +username);
}
```

My code on the second page:

```
protected void TextBoxUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var username = Request.QueryString["USERNAME"];
}
```

Comment: So does it work as expected? If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: no its not working, when i click the row in grid view, it redirected to the next page without any username in the text box. It supposed to pass the username from gridview.

Comment: i have edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're looking for the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event of the `GridView`.

```
protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    var username = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("ViewUploads.aspx?USERNAME=" +username);
}
```

In the next page(`ViewUploads.aspx`) you need to  assign it to the TextBox' `Text`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack && Request.QueryString["USERNAME"] != null)
        this.txtUserName.Text = Request.QueryString["USERNAME"];
}
```

I'm not sure if you have already done that, if you want to use the `DataKeys`-collection in the first page, you have to set the `DataKeyNames` property accordingly. For example:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
    datakeynames="UserName"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanging"
    runat="server">
     ...
</asp:gridview>
```